# Improve Regular Expression with optional values

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

(Working with Regex in C#)

I've several regular expresions to parse a line in several fields. One of this fields have an optional char that I can't figure how to make my regex to split it. I tried to improve it in one line but I couldn't do it.

My input:

```
4-002 TERMO CONTINENTAL 1 L N°3995 9.22 4-003 TERMO CONTINENTAL 2 N°3996 99.22
```

My desidered output:

```
Item[0].Code = 4-002
Item[0].Detail = TERMO CONTINENTAL 1 L N°3995
Item[0].Price = 9.22

Item[1].Code = 4-003
Item[1].Detail = TERMO CONTINENTAL 2 N°3996
Item[1].Price = 99.22
```

My last attempt:

To separete both items: `(?=\d\-\d\d\d\s.*)`
This is not working because some codes are: like `14-001` instead `4-001`
I tried with: `([\d]\d\-\d\d\d\s.*)` but neither works

**QUESTION**:
How can I retrieve both possibilities? `14-001` and `4-001`

And in the other things are related to this problem:
To separate detail from price: `([^\s]*$)` (from one item splitted before)
To separate code from detail: `(\d\-\d\d\d\s)` (same problem as original question)

Any help with this regular expression will be helpful and valorated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this: (\d+-\d+)\s([^\d]+\d\s(L\s)?N°\d+)\s(\d+\.\d+) - Although I recommend parsing this correctly with .Split, etc..

Comment: Try [`(\d+-\d+)\s+(.*?)\s+(\d+\.\d+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5cd%2b-%5cd%2b)%5cs%2b(.*%3f)%5cs%2b(%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b)&i=4-002+TERMO+CONTINENTAL+1+L+N%c2%b03995+9.22+4-003+TERMO+CONTINENTAL+2+N%c2%b03996+99.22).

Comment: You can use `[\d]{1,2}-[\d]{3}` for the first part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following regex is safe to use:

```
(\d+-\d+)\s+(.*?N°\d+)\s+(\d+\.\d+)
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5Cd%2B-%5Cd%2B)%5Cs%2B(.*%3FN%C2%B0%5Cd%2B)%5Cs%2B(%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%2B)&i=4-002%20TERMO%20CONTINENTAL%201%20L%20N%C2%B03995%209.22%204-003%20TERMO%20CONTINENTAL%202%20N%C2%B03996%2099.22)

If the `Item.Detail` can have any text and it is located between a `digits`-`digits` and a float value,  use

```
(\d+-\d+)\s+(.*?)\s+(\d+\.\d+)
```

See [another demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5Cd%2B-%5Cd%2B)%5Cs%2B(.%2A%3F)%5Cs%2B(%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd%2B)&i=4-002%20TERMO%20CONTINENTAL%201%20L%20N%C2%B03995%209.22%204-003%20TERMO%20CONTINENTAL%202%20N%C2%B03996%2099.22)

Results:

[image]

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/VfFb1I)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(\d+-\d\d\d)(.*?)(\d+\.\d\d)
```

The `+` is for one or more occurrences.